# iOS - Google Analytics for one page

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have created a game for iOS and I want to be able to track when people are playing.

By this, I simply mean I want to know how often people are opening the app (and thus find out if users are returning or playing it only once).

Because of this, I don't want to have to include the entire Google Analysics SDK in my project. Does anyone know if it's possible to make a request from in an iOS app (possibly using NSURLRequest?) to call Google Analytics and make it think a web page has been visited?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant help with the IOS bit but you can send the raw posts to Google analytics on your own :https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#proxy-server-tracking